# Index i is either negative or above row count in BindingSource c#

Tags: c#, datagridview, bindingsource

When i Invoke the Event , it throws an error like  Index (int)i either negative or above row count.

What can i do.. . 
`public void UserDeletingEvent (object sender, EventArg e)
{
    BindingSource.RemoveAt(e.row.index);
}`

Comment: not possible to answer sensibly from the information given....

Comment: Well what debugging have you done? What's the value of `e.row.index`? (That doesn't look like it should even compile, by the way...)

Answer (score 1):

Check that `e.Row.Index` is greater than 0, there are reasons that it could be -1 which is an invalid index in the `BindingSource`.

```
public void UserDeletingEvent(object sender, EventArg e)
{
    if (e.Row.Index >= 0)
    {
        BindingSource.RemoveAt(e.Row.Index);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I found the index did not represent an actual row when the user clicked on the heading or the background area.  You have to test that it is a valid index.

Answer (score -2):

try
pgitems.CurrentPageIndex = PageNumber;

setting that to nothing made it work for me, im building pagig for repeater, done the job